# Write-Host strips newline characters where Write-Output does not

Tags: powershell

The command `$output = Invoke-Expression "cfn-lint *.yaml"` gives me an array for `$output`:

```
$output.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

`Write-Output $output` gives me this nice output:

```
Write-Output $output
W2506 Parameter AMIID should be of type [AWS::EC2::Image::Id, 
AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>]
trace3-ec2-virtual-machine-creation.yaml:27:3

W2001 Parameter VpcId not used.
trace3-ec2-virtual-machine-creation.yaml:32:3
```

But `Write-Host $output` gives me a version with all the newlines stripped out:

```
Write-Host $output                                                                                                                                                                                                                
W2506 Parameter AMIID should be of type [AWS::EC2::Image::Id, AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>] trace3-ec2-virtual-machine-creation.yaml:27:3  W2001 Parameter VpcId not used. trace3-ec2-virtual-machine-creation.yaml:32:3
```

Why is it doing this?

I know that I can get around this with the call `Write-Host ($output | Out-String)`, but I don't understand why that works.

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Output` takes `[-InputObject] <PSObject[]>` as argument while `Write-Host` takes `[[-Object] <Object>]` as argument.

> [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) returns the objects that are submitted as input.

> [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) sends the objects to the host. It does not return any objects. However, the host displays the objects that Write-Host sends to it.

As you can see, `Write-Ouput` takes an `array` of `PSObject` as **Input** parameter and returns the same `array` as **Output**.

`Out-String` works fine with `Write-Host` because it is converting your array to a `multiline string` hence `Write-Host` will return it as literal to the **Information Stream** while without the `Out-String` it is taking all lines of your array and joining them into a single line string.

```
PS /> $test = @(
    'this is a'
    'test'
)

$writeHost = Write-Host -Object $test 6>&1
$writeOutput = Write-Output -Object $test

$writeHost.GetType()
$writeOutput.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                       
True     False    InformationRecord                        System.Object                                                                                                  
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

#### Edit

Following your comment, I don't know for sure why, I couldn't find any relevant information on MS Docs for the cmdlet but we can assume it is doing some sort of manipulation on the input objects. We do know that `Write-Host` is a wrapper for `Write-Information`.

Take this function as an example, it receives a `[object]` in this case it receives an `array` with 2 items as input and writes to the information stream a `string` representation of it's input:

```
$test = @(
    'this is a'
    'test'
)

function TestString ([object]$String) {
    Write-Information ([string]$String) -InformationAction Continue
}

PS /> TestString $test
this is a test
```

Comment: Why does Write-Host take all the lines of the array and convert them into a single-line string?

Comment: @PortMan My assumption is because of how it is coded, but I can't be sure honestly. It is possible that it is coded to get rid of all `new lines` and `carriage returns` and join them into a single line string.

Comment: @PortMan I added an edit to my answer, hope it makes some sense.